# TeeChart WPF - Change Series Type Issues - Leaves Original, Blends Styles

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, teechart

So I am working on building a WPF TeeChart Editor, but I am having some issues with trying to change the Type of a Series on a chart using the static method:
`Steema.TeeChart.WPF.Styles.Series.ChangeType(ref Series s, Type newType)`

Original code idea:

```
//user has selected a sample chart showing the Series Type they want
Type targetType = selectedChart.Series[0].GetType();

//SelectedItems contains Series objects already on a chart
for (int i = 0; i < SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{
    Series sS = (Series) SelectedItems[i];
    Series.ChangeType(ref sS, targetType);
}
```

When the above code runs, my chart ends up with two series: the original, and a new series that is some blend of the original and the target.

For example, if I put a Points Series on the Chart with 4 random values, then run the above code with the only thing in SelectedItems being the points series I just created, my chart has a new series of type Line but with point markers on it, as well as the original Points Series.

I modified the above code to remove duplicates, then I realized something was removing the other items from the SelectedItems collection. Below is the final code that removes the original Series and also works when multiple Series are in the SelectedItems collection.

```
//Added List to keep selected items since they were being lost
List<Series> selected = new List<Series>(SelectedItems.Count);
for (int x = 0; x < SelectedItems.Count; x++)
    selected.Add((Series) SelectedItems[x]);


for (int i = 0; i < selected.Count; i++)
{
    Series sS = selected[i];
    int cI = chart.Series.IndexOf(sS); //added to track index in chart

    Series.ChangeType(ref sS, targetType);

    //The following line ensures overwite of original Series in chart
    // since new Series is being created inside above method
    chart.Series[cI] = sS;

    //finally, remove original Series from chart
    chart.Series.Remove(selected[i]);
}
```

That fixes the problem with it leaving the original Series on the chart, but I still cannot figure out why the Style of the Series is becoming some strange blend of the original and the target Series Type.

Is there something I am missing or overlooking in my approach? Is there a better method to call to change the type of a Series? I was unable to find any useful information in the TeeChart documentation.

I do not think this behavior is intended because when I compare the output I am getting from this method with the WinForms TeeChart Editor, the WinForms version does not blend the styles of the Series.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is a bug of TeeChartWPF and we have added it in bug list report with number [TW16016232]. We will try to fix it to upcoming maintenance releases of TeeChartFor.Net. On the other hand, I suggest you a workaround to solve your problem, it consist in do that the source series are replaced for Points Series, in this case.

```
 private void InitializeChart()
        {
            tChart1.Series.Clear();
            Steema.TeeChart.WPF.Styles.Line line1 = new Steema.TeeChart.WPF.Styles.Line(tChart1.Chart);
            Steema.TeeChart.WPF.Styles.Line line2 = new Steema.TeeChart.WPF.Styles.Line(tChart1.Chart);
            line2.FillSampleValues();
            line1.FillSampleValues();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                Steema.TeeChart.WPF.Styles.Points s = new Steema.TeeChart.WPF.Styles.Points(tChart1.Chart);
                s.DataSource = tChart1[i];
                tChart1[i].Visible = false;
            }

        }
```

Can you tell us, if previous code works as you expect, at the moment?

I hope will help.

Thanks,

Best Regards, 
Sandra Pazos

Steema Support Central 
[http://www.steema.com/](http://www.steema.com)